# Mosquitto dynamic security does not allow to insert clients or roles

Tags: docker, plugins, mqtt, mosquitto

Hi everyone I've been trying to use mosquitto dynamic security plugin, the broker is running in a docker container, and so far everything seems to work as expected I can generate de file dynamic-secutiry.json for that I used the following command `mosquitto_ctrl dynsec init path/to/dynamic-security.json user` and after that, I set the password as **user**, so managed to open the file and make sure that it was created right, and indeed it was. However, when I try to modify the file like adding a new client for instance I got the following message `Connection error: Not authorized` in order to add new clients I've been something like this `mosquitto_ctrl -u user -P user dynsec createRole rolepizza` and then I'm getting this:
[image]

That's the dynamic-security.json

[image]

Finally my mosquitto.conf
[image]

I've been following this tutorials:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QvRBtRH2mN0

http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/understanding-mosquitto-dynamic-security-plugin/

I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me what I've been doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do not post images of text, post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it. Images are hard to read, impossible for people who use screen readers and you can't search for them.

Comment: Check the broker logs and what permissions the JSON file has (the broker runs as user 1883, but I think the default shell user is root)

Comment: @hardillb Thanks for replying, and you were right the problem was the file's permissions I had to change the owner and the writing permissions. Sorry for the question I didn't know about the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hashed out in the comments, the problem was most likely a lack of write permissions on `dynamic-security.json` file due to creating it as root.

Mosquitto will normally drop root permissions on startup, so all config/log files should be writable by a none privileged user (you can set the user in the `mosquitto.conf` file.